# Converting traditional nested if else condition to java 8 optionals efficiently

Tags: java

```
Object ab = someMethod1()

if(ab != null) {
        someMethod2(ab);
} else {
       someMethod3()
}
```

converted to java optionals

```
Optional.ofNullable(someMethod1()).map( e ->   someMethod2(ab))
          .orElseGet(() ->  someMethod3() );
```

but for the can you please help me out out to convert
// Multiple nested if else  conditions are there , finding difficulty to convert to java 8  optionals

```
  public void  a() {
        Object ab = someMethod1();        
        if(ab != null) {
               Object cd = someMethod2();       
                  if(cd !=  null) {       
                      Object ef = someMethod3();    
                      if( ef!= null) {         
                            someMethod4();               
                      } else {        
                           elseMethod3()                         
                      }       
                   
                  } else {
                    elseMethod2()
                  }    
        } else {     
            elseMethod1();    
        }   
    }
```

Comment: just redo the same change you did for the first case, using nested optionals, ... and making your code unreadable, optional does not have to be used for that

Answer (score 0):

```
public class a {

    static String method1(String agr) {
        return "method1";
    }
    
    static String method2(String agr) {
        return "method2";
    }
    
    static String method3(String agr) {
        return "method3";
    }
    
    public static Optional<String> cal(Optional<String> optionalS, Function<String, String> function, String agr) {
        if (optionalS.isPresent())
            return Optional.of(function.apply(agr));
    
        return Optional.empty();
    }
    
    public static void main(String agr[]) {
        cal(Optional.empty(), a::method1, "agr func1").orElseGet(() ->
            cal(Optional.empty(), a::method2, "agr func2").orElseGet(() ->
                cal(Optional.ofNullable("c"), a::method3, "agr func3").orElse("final result")
            )
        );
    }
}
```